# Get first frame of video rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, ffmpeg, paperclip, carrierwave

i get video file in params how can i get a first frame as picture from this video using paperclip or carrierwave or other gems?

video in params looks like this:

```
 #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fc598ab45b8
 @content_type="video/mp4",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"Resource 
Prospector Mobility Test.mp4\"\r\n" + "Content-Type: video/mp4\r\n",
 @original_filename="Resource Prospector Mobility Test.mp4",
 @tempfile=#
<File:/var/folders/cy/q0_j47kn24l58ff4tqlxzsjc0000gq/T/RackMultipart20170720-
6218-1cna8ld.mp4>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do it using a file upload gem alone -- you'll have to use something else, just like using ImageMagick (or RMagick or similar) to process thumbnails from an uploaded image.

`convert input.mp4[X] thumbnail.png` where X is a frame.

more at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/video/#gif

The best server-side choice is likely ffmpeg. You should be able to follow the same general steps you'd use to thumbnail an image (upload, process in a background job, etc) with ImageMagick.

If you're using a third-party video solution (YouTube, Wistia, etc) there is likely an API call you can use to generate a thumbnail after you send the file to their service.

Comment: i tried to use ffmpeg, wrote this line

FFMPEG::Movie.new(Rails.root.join('lovetherents.mov').to_s)

and get an error "Could not parse output from FFProbe" 

what can it be?
path correct

Answer (score 0):

resolved using ffmpeg

> gem 'streamio-ffmpeg', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.2'

had trouble with "Could not parse output from FFProbe" but resolved it with reinstalling ffmpeg

> brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-libass --with-sdl2 --with-x265 --with-freetype --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opus

Comment: Sweet! Glad that solved the problem -- its always a matter of figuring out the extra libraries with the linux media conversion tools :/